# Jlabel cannot be applied;reason: actual and formal argument list differ in length

Tags: java, swing, compiler-errors, jframe, jlabel

I'm studying for an upcoming exam and the professor gave us nothing but this book to learn and i'm learning so far but I got an error on the Jlabel code that the book provided

code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
public class JLabel extends JFrame
{
    private int Width = 400;
    private int Height = 300;

    private JLabel LengthL, WidthL, AreaL, PerimeterL;

    public JLabel()
    {
        setTitle("Area and Perimeter of a Rectangle");

        LengthL = new JLabel("Enter the length: ", SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        WidthL = new JLabel("Enter the width: ", SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        AreaL = new JLabel("Area: ", SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        PerimeterL = new JLabel("Perimeter: ", SwingConstants.RIGHT);

        Container Pane = getContentPane();
        Pane.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,1));

        Pane.add(LengthL);
        Pane.add(WidthL);
        Pane.add(AreaL);
        Pane.add(PerimeterL);

        setSize(Width, Height);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }

    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        JLabel JL = new JLabel();
    }
}
```

Error:

```
Constructor Jlabel in class JLabel cannot be applied to given types;
required: no arguments
found: java.lang.String, int
reason: actual and formal argument list differ in length
```

Expected output according to the book:

[image]

sorry for the beginner question i'm looking at this sample code and can't seem to find the error

Comment: Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently.

Comment: ohhh thankyou I'll remeber tis nomentclatures. But sorry for the question when will this "UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT" be used?

Comment: If the `final` modifier is used when declaring the attribute, it is a constant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is that you have called your class JLabel. The compiler is then trying to use this class when compiling, instead of the JLabel found in the javax.swing.* package that your book is expecting it to use.

We can tell this is the case because in the error message it states `required: no arguments`. The constructor you have implemented does not take any arguments and you don't have any constructors available with the arguments `String, int`, so the compiler is looking for a constructor that doesnt exist.

To solve this just change the name of your class to something else (like LabelTest or MyLabel etc).

The compiler will now use the JLabel class found in java.swing which has a few different constructors available, including the one that this book is expecting it to use.

A quick note on what is often considered good practice:
When importing, you should aim to import only the classes you need rather than the entire package, so

```
import  javax.swing.*;
```

is importing the entire [javax.swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/package-summary.html) package, when in reality you only need a few classes from it. Instead you should try and use:

```
import  javax.swing.JLabel;
```

This imports the specific class and helps to make it clearer which classes are being imported and used. It also helps you within your code to identify the origin of each class being used.

To give the full fix :

```
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

public class LabelTest extends JFrame
{
    private int Width = 400;
    private int Height = 300;

    private JLabel LengthL, WidthL, AreaL, PerimeterL;

    public LabelTest()
    {
        setTitle("Area and Perimeter of a Rectangle");

        LengthL = new JLabel("Enter the length: ", SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        WidthL = new JLabel("Enter the width: ", SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        AreaL = new JLabel("Area: ", SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        PerimeterL = new JLabel("Perimeter: ", SwingConstants.RIGHT);

        Container Pane = getContentPane();
        Pane.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,1));

        Pane.add(LengthL);
        Pane.add(WidthL);
        Pane.add(AreaL);
        Pane.add(PerimeterL);

        setSize(Width, Height);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }

    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        LabelTest JL = new LabelTest();
    }
}
```

hope this helps!

Comment: Ohhh thankyou did not even think that the a class name can disrupt the program